# Equivalent of count list function in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix `listScore` with the shape (100000,2): I would like to count all the identical rows like. For instance, if `listScore` was a list of list I would simple do:

```
listScore.count([2,0])
```

to look for all the list equal to [2,0].
I could obviously transform the type of my `listScore` so that it would be a list but I want to keep to effectiveness of `numpy`. Is there any function I could use to do the same thing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `listScore` is a NumPy array, you could do -

```
count = np.all(listScore == np.array([2,0]),axis=1).sum()
```

If the array is always a 2 columns array, then you can compare the two columns separately with `2` and `0` respectively for performance and get the count like so -

```
count = ((listScore[:,0] ==2) & (listScore[:,1] ==0)).sum()
```

If you are a fan of [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), you might like to try this *twisted* one -

```
count = (~np.einsum('ij->i',listScore != [2,0])).sum()
```

Another performance-oriented solution could be with [`cdist from scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
count = (cdist(listScore,np.atleast_2d([2,0]))==0).sum()
```

Comment: Very complete answer ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

For a `numpy.matrix`, you can use:

```
(listScore==listScore[ind]).all(1).sum()
```

to find the number of rows matching the row with index `ind`.

or

```
(listScore==[2,0]).all(1).sum()
```

to match a specific pattern